# tkinter: No input possible after messagebox is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, input, warnings

I want to call a messagebox (with messagebox.showwarning) at the start of my program to inform the user about something.
When the user clicks on "Ok", a GUI opens. There the user can make inputs.

*Problem*: No input is possible after the warning is displayed. Without the warning window the input works without any problems.

Is there a solution that the user can provide input?

I have included a code snippet here:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('420x100')

# Input doesn't work after the messagebox
messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Some Serious Warning.")

# Label
li = Label(root, text="Input 1")
li.grid(row=0, column=0)
li = Label(root, text="Input 2")
li.grid(row=0, column=2)
li = Label(root, text="Dropdown")
li.grid(row=1, column=0)
li = Label(root, text="Input 3")
li.grid(row=1, column=2)

# Input
url_text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=url_text)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Dropdown Menu
OptionList = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
]
input1 = StringVar()
input1.set(OptionList[0])
e3 = tk.OptionMenu(root, input1, *OptionList)
e3.config(width=12, font=('Helvetica', 9))
e3.grid(row=1, column=1)

input2 = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(root, textvariable=input2)
e2.grid(row=0, column=3)

input3 = StringVar()
e4 = Entry(root, textvariable=input3)
e4.grid(row=1, column=3)

# Button
b1 = Button(root, text="Run", width=12)
b1.grid(row=2, column=1)

b2 = Button(root, text="Help", width=12)
b2.grid(row=2, column=2)

b3 = Button(root, text="Exit", width=12)
b3.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=(10, 10))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `root.wait_visibility()` or `root.update()` before showing the message box:

```
root.wait_visibility()  # or root.update()
messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Some Serious Warning.")
```

Or get the focus using `foucs_force()` after showing the message box:

```
messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Some Serious Warning.")
root.focus_force()
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier when you were agreeing to the messagebox your gui was getting build in the window created by the messagebox which was locking your labels. Using the class method fixed this issue but the window created by the messagebox needs to be manually closed.
I suggest not to use message box rather create a label or a new window as your error box.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class app:
    def __init__(self):
        hi=messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Some Serious Warning.")
    
        self.window=tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry('420x100')

        # Label
        li = Label(self.window, text="Input 1")
        li.grid(row=0, column=0)
        li = Label(self.window, text="Input 2")
        li.grid(row=0, column=2)
        li = Label(self.window, text="Dropdown")
        li.grid(row=1, column=0)
        li = Label(self.window, text="Input 3")
        li.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # Input
        url_text = StringVar()
        e1 = Entry(self.window, textvariable=url_text)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # Dropdown Menu
        OptionList = [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
        input1 = StringVar()
        input1.set(OptionList[0])
        e3 = tk.OptionMenu(self.window, input1, *OptionList)
        e3.config(width=12, font=('Helvetica', 9))
        e3.grid(row=1, column=1)

        input2 = StringVar()
        e2 = Entry(self.window, textvariable=input2)
        e2.grid(row=0, column=3)

        input3 = StringVar()
        e4 = Entry(self.window, textvariable=input3)
        e4.grid(row=1, column=3)

        # Button
        b1 = Button(self.window, text="Run", width=12)
        b1.grid(row=2, column=1)

        b2 = Button(self.window, text="Help", width=12)
        b2.grid(row=2, column=2)

        b3 = Button(self.window, text="Exit", width=12)
        b3.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=(10, 10))
    
game=app()
game.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This indeed solves the problem. If the messagebox is set after self.window = tk.Tk(), no empty window is called either. So should also be a solution